# add highlight class to the label of a checked check box via a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checked all over stack overflow, but they're not exactly what I need.
I have checkboxes with associated labels

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="dog" id="dg" />
  <label for="dg">Dog</label>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="cat" id="ct" />
  <label for="ct">Cats</label></p>
<p>

<p><input type="button" id='bt' value="Record" /></p>
```

There is also a button, when the button is clicked, if the checkbox is checked, the label associated with it has a highlight class added to the label. I already have the highlight class written I am just having trouble applying it using the addClass method.

I have:

```
         $(':checkbox:checked').addClass('highlight');
```

but it does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Okay, I think I understand what you need. See updated example.

---

The trick is knowing how to find the label and checkbox associated with the button. Since the buttons were not included in the question code, I had to guess. If the button is elsewhere, you can experiment using [these jQuery traversing methods.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_traversing.asp)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
  var chkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
  $(chkboxes).each(function(){
     if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
         $(this).parent().find('label').addClass('highlight');
     }else{
         $(this).parent().find('label').removeClass('highlight');
     }
  });
});
  
}); //END document.ready
```

```css
.highlight{background:red;color:yellow;padding:2px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="dog" id="dg" />
  <label for="dg">Dog</label>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="cat" id="ct" />
  <label for="ct">Cats</label>
<p>
<button id="mybutt">Go</button>
```

Comment: there is one button underneath the checkboxes <p><input type="button" id='bt' value="Record" /></p>

Comment: So how do you know which checkbox to examine? It is possible that both are checkmarked.

Comment: thank you no answers are working when I copy and paste them gotta figure out what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @Kann You must wrap the javascript/jQuery code in a `document.ready` wrapper. See my updated answer. *The reason why you need this is because the jQuery code BINDS events (i.e. click) to HTML tags. If the page has not rendered those tags when the super-fast javascript code runs, then the binding fails and the code cannot detect the click event on the button.*

Answer (score 1):

Let's say this is your HTML:

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="dog" id="dg" />
  <label for="dg">Dog</label>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="cat" id="ct" />
  <label for="ct">Cats</label></p>
<p>
<p>
  <button id="btnSubmit">Click Me!</button>
</p>
```

and this is your CSS class:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

One thing you could do is loop through each checked checkbox and just apply the class using the `label[for=*]` property:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").addClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

However, using the above method, you're not allowing a way to remove the highlight class should you uncheck a box and hit Submit again.  I would prefer the below method... which loops through ALL checkboxes, and tests them to determine if they're checked or not:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").addClass("highlight");
        } else {
            $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });
});
```

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xgbgnb8/)

I'm trying to find a way to just reference the label of all checked checkboxes in one line of code.  Because if you could do that, you can just do away with the looping and the if statements.  I'll keep researching, and if I find it, I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: the button looks like this <p><input type="button" id='bt' value="Record" /></p>

Comment: Well then I think it should be the same, you just need to change $('#btnSubmit') to $('#bt').  Or, change the id of your input button to something that makes more sense ;)

Comment: Yup, you got it -- and you understood the question better than I did. Well done, +1

Comment: thank you no answers are working when I copy and paste them gotta figure out what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I guess, what you are trying to do is to change a class, after the value of your checkbox has changed, easiest way to do this is using the `onChange` event, you can also bind the event with jQuery using `$('#your_checkbox').on('change', function(){})`

```js
$('[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  if (!$(this).attr('checked')) {
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
  } else if ($(this).attr('checked') === 'checked') {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked', '');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('checked');
  }
});

$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function() {
  var inputs = $(this).parent().parent().find('[type="checkbox"]')
  inputs.each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('checked') === 'checked') {
      $(this).parent().addClass('iam-checked');
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('iam-checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.checked {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.iam-checked {
  background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="dog" id="dg" />
  <label for="dg">Dog</label>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="cat" id="ct" />
  <label for="ct">Cats</label></p>
<p>
<p>
  <button id="btnSubmit">Click Me!</button>
</p>
```

Comment: thank you no answers are working when I copy and paste them gotta figure out what i'm doing wrong

Comment: You should take care of how you are traversing through your DOM, take a look on this page: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp and read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but I was surprised that no one mentioned the `next` method. You are trying to style the label after the checkbox, not the checkbox itself. In other words, the label is the next sibling of the checkbox.

I think this is the most jQuery way to solve this so wanted to add my two cents.

```js
$("#bt").on("click", function() {
    $(":checked").each(function() {
        $(this).next().addClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

```css
.highlight { background: gold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="dog" id="dg" />
  <label for="dg">Dog</label>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="cat" id="ct" />
  <label for="ct">Cats</label></p>
<p>

<p><input type="button" id='bt' value="Record" /></p>
```